# Calling ajaxWatermark extender in javascript

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

i have a  Ajax Control toolkit water mark extender for a search box which is there in a master page . Based on certain condition ,i would like to change this value from the child page which inherits from this master page .I want to do it in client side with jquery /javascript . Any ideas??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a javascript function that change the watermark, andd just call it from your child page

```
function setWatermarkText(text)
{
  var watermark = $get('<%= WatermarkExtender.ClientID %>');
  watermark.set_Text("John Smith");
}
```